Change width and height according to scale using tailwind
I am trying to adapt the width and height of each li element, so that they don't overlap when active (scale: 5). Anyone knows how can I achieve this? Thank you :)
The navbar snippet:
<ul
  className={`${
    menuMobile ? 'flex' : 'hidden'
  } flex-col text-3xl sm:flex sm:flex-row sm:gap-2 justify-center sm:text-base`}>
  {navItems.map((navItem) => (
    <li>
      <FlipLink
        href={navItem.link}
        isActive={activeLink === navItem.id}
        onClick={(e) => {
          handleClick(navItem.id);
        }}>
        {navItem.name}
      
    </li>
  ))}
</ul>

This is the FlipLink component:
const FlipLink = ({ children, href, isActive, onClick }) => {
  const desktopAnimation = useDesktop();

  const variants = {
    active: desktopAnimation ? { scale: 5 } : {},
  };

  const transition = {
    duration: 0.4,
    ease: 'easeInOut',
  };

  return (
    <motion.a
      initial='initial'
      whileHover='hovered'
      animate={isActive ? 'active' : 'initial'}
      href={href}
      onClick={onClick}
      className={`relative inline-block overflow-hidden whitespace-nowrap sm:text-7xl md:text-8xl lg:text-  9xl`}
      style={{ lineHeight: 1 }}
      variants={variants}
      transition={transition}>
    </motion.a>
  );
};

I already tried to style using something like this but didn't work:
'--scale': activeLink === navItem.id ? 5 : 1,
transform: 'scale(var(--scale))',
transformOrigin: 'center center',
margin: 'calc((var(--scale) - 1) * 100%)',
transition: 'transform 0.25s ease-in-out, margin 0.25s ease-in-out',

